# Having trouble emitting an Angular 13 message to a component but it is SENDING

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a SERVICE that emits the ID, TITLE and MESSAGE for a modal, hence using one modal for many faces; polymorphism, actually.

I can SEND the emitted message but getting it to show up in the generic.modal.component.ts is not happening as expected.

Here's my code (abridged version for brevity)

this is a snippet from my ***component.ts*** file

```
  // Top of the code
  @Output() setAddress: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() setModalID: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() setModalTitle: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() setModalContent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<object>();

  message = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    msg: '',
    msgObj: {}
  };

  // ... some more code...

  openModal(id: string, title: string): void {
    console.log('Modal will open...' + id);
    this.modalService.setID(id);
    this.modalService.setTitle(id, title);
    this.modalService.setMsg(id, "This is the Example Modal Body");
    this.setModalAction(id, title, this.modalService.getMsg());
    this.commonService.showHideGenericModal('button');
  }

  setModalAction(id: string, title: any, msg: any): void {
    this.message.id = id;
    this.message.title = title;
    this.message.msg = msg;
    // Send Message to emit
    this.sendMessage();
  }

  // Send Message Object to be listened for
  sendMessage(): void {
    console.log('Sending Message: ', this.message);
    this.messageEvent.emit(this.message);
  }
```

***common-svcs.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'angular-web-storage';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ModalService } from './modal.service';
import { VaForm21elementService } from './vaForm21.element.service';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    initAutocomplete: () => void;
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonSvcsService implements OnInit {

  modalMsg: string = '';
  modalID: string = '';
  modalTitle: string = '';

  private _messageDetails: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  public messageDetailsObs = this._messageDetails.asObservable();

  ... some more code

    constructor(
    private sessionStorageService: SessionStorageService,
    private modalService: ModalService,
    private vaform21Service: VaForm21elementService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.initAutocomplete = this.initAutocomplete;
    if (this.isGenericModalOpen) {
      this.isGenericModalOpen = false;
      this.sessionStorageService.set('isGenericModalOpen', this.isGenericModalOpen);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sessionStorageService.remove('isGenericModalOpen');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.isGenericModalOpen) {
      this.isGenericModalOpen = false;
      this.sessionStorageService.set('isGenericModalOpen', this.isGenericModalOpen);
    }
  }

  showHideGenericModal(fromwhere: string): void {
    switch (fromwhere) {
      case "voice":
      case "button":
        this.openModalDialog();
        break;
      case "close":
        this.closeModalDialog();
        break;
    }
  }

  /**
 * Open Generic Modal
 */
  public openModalDialog(): void {
    this.genericModal = document.getElementsByClassName('drag-block')[0] as HTMLElement;

    this.isGenericModalOpen = this.sessionStorageService.get('isGenericModalOpen');
    if (!this.isGenericModalOpen) {
      this.isGenericModalOpen = true;
      this.sessionStorageService.set('isGenericModalOpen', this.isGenericModalOpen);
      console.log('Inside openGenericModal: ', this.genericModal);
      this.id = this.modalService.getID();
      this.modalTitle = this.modalService.getTitle();
      this.modalMsg = this.modalService.getMsg();
      this.genericModal.classList.add('show')
      this.isGenericModalOpen = false;
      this.sessionStorageService.set('isGenericModalOpen', this.isGenericModalOpen);
    } else {
      // ('The modal is already opened');
    }
  }

}
```

***modal.service.ts***

```
export class ModalService {
  modals: any[] = [];
  modalTitle!: string;
  modalMsg!: string;
  id!: string;
  showModal: boolean = false;

  theModal!: HTMLElement;

  add(modal: any) {
    // add modal to array of active modals
    this.modals.push(modal);
  }

  remove(id: string) {
    // remove modal from array of active modals
    this.modals = this.modals.filter(x => x.id !== id);
  }

  open(id: string): boolean {
    // open modal specified by id
    const modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    return this.showModal = false;
  }

  close(id: string): boolean {
    // close modal specified by id
    const modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    return this.showModal = true;
  }

  setTitle(id: string, title: string) {
    // Sets the title
    const modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    this.modalTitle = title;
    // modal.title = title;
  }

  setMsg(id: string, msg: string) {
    // Sets the title
    const modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    this.modalMsg = msg;
    // modal.msg = msg;
  }

  setID(id: string): void {
    this.id = id;
  }

  getID(): string {
    return this.id;
  }

  // Get Modal Title
  getTitle(): string {
    return this.modalTitle;
  }
  // Get Modal Msg/Body
  getMsg(): string {
    return this.modalMsg;
  }

}
```

Finally, the ***generic.modal.component.ts and html*** files respectively

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'angular-web-storage';
import { CommonSvcsService } from 'src/app/services/common-svcs.service';
import { ModalService } from 'src/app/services/modal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mymodal',
  templateUrl: './generic-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generic-modal.component.css']
})
export class GenericModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() my_modal_title!: string;
  @Input() my_modal_content!: string;
  @Input() id: string = '';
  @ViewChild('messageEvent') messageAction: any;
  showModal: boolean = false;

  @ViewChild('el') el: ElementRef | undefined;

  private element: any;
  private isGenericModalOpen: boolean = false;
  private message!: object;

  constructor(
    private modalService: ModalService,
    private sessionStorageService: SessionStorageService,
    private commonService: CommonSvcsService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const modal = this;
    this.element = this.el?.nativeElement;
    this.modalService.add(this);

    if (this.isGenericModalOpen) {
      this.isGenericModalOpen = false;
      this.sessionStorageService.remove('isGenericModalOpen');
    }

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.id = this.commonService.modalID;
     this.my_modal_title = this.commonService.modalTitle;
     this.my_modal_content = this.commonService.modalMsg;
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.commonService.messageDetailsObs.subscribe((messageDetails) => {
      console.log('Message Details: ', messageDetails)
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.modalService.remove(this.id);
    this.element.remove();
    this.sessionStorageService.remove('isGenericModalOpen');
  }

  // open modal
  public open(): void {
    // this.element.style.display = 'block';
    // document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
    this.showModal = this.modalService.open(this.id);
  }

  // close modal
  public close(): void {
    // this.element.style.display = 'none';
    // document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
    this.showModal = false;
    this.commonService.showHideGenericModal('close');
  }

  // Set Modal Title
  public setTitle(title: string): void {
    this.my_modal_title = this.modalService.getTitle();
    this.modalService.setTitle(this.id, title);
  }

  // Set Modal Message
  public setMsg(msg: string): void {
    this.my_modal_content = this.modalService.getMsg();
    this.modalService.setMsg(this.id, msg);
  }

  // Set the ID of the modal dynamically
  public setID(id: string): void {
    this.id = id;
  }

  // Get the ID of the modal set
  public getID(): string {
    return this.id;
  }

  public receiveMessage($event: any): void {
    this.message = $event;
    console.log('Received Message: ', this.message);
  }

}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="modal fade drag-block" (messageAction)="receiveMessage($event)" id="{{id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true" [ngClass]="{'show': showModal}">
  <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{my_modal_title}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true" (click)="close()">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{my_modal_content}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing is dynamically feeding the ID, TITLE and MSG into a modal so I can send into it anything and use only one modal component. I getting is:   private message!: object; is UNDEFINED

BTW: the modal OPENS and the buttons and "x" are there. Nothing is in the TITLE, MSG or ID

Thank you

**UPDATE:**
So, here's my minor issue after @Krenom helped me.

I'm going to reduce this for simplicity:

main-form.component.ts
main-form.component.html <-- this will fire 1 to "n" number of modals

generic-modal.component.ts
generic-modal.component.html <-- this will RECEIVE the msgObj which is outline both in my question and @Krenom's solution.

common-svc.service.ts <-- talks to any component that imports this

All of these components and service live under src/app/

The components are under /components and the services live under /services under app/

Now that that's done.

**The Problem**
the msgObj gets populated nicely. BUT even with me sending the messageObject via an Observable or the updateModal function that @Krenom created the fact remains, that I need to be able to change the {{title}} and {{msg}} in the generic-modal.component.ts from the common-svc.service.ts when the msgObj changes.

That's all.

I am STILL keeping @Krenoms solution, I probably just am missing something

Here is the full generic-modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewRef } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'angular-web-storage';
import { CommonSvcsService } from 'src/app/services/common-svcs.service';
import { ModalService } from 'src/app/services/modal.service';
import { GenericModalObj } from '../va-form-21/vaForm21.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mymodal',
  templateUrl: './generic-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generic-modal.component.css']
})
export class GenericModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() my_modal_title!: string;
  @Input() my_modal_content!: string;
  @Input() id: string = '';
  @ViewChild('messageEvent') messageAction: any;
  showModal: boolean = false;
  @Input() public set data(value: any) {
    this.message = value;
    this.data();
  }

  @ViewChild('el') el: ElementRef | undefined;

  private element: any;
  private isGenericModalOpen: boolean = false;
  public message!: object;

  constructor(
    private modalService: ModalService,
    private sessionStorageService: SessionStorageService,
    private commonService: CommonSvcsService,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  msgObj!: GenericModalObj;

  ngOnInit() {
    const modal = this;
    this.element = this.el?.nativeElement;
    this.modalService.add(this);

    if (this.isGenericModalOpen) {
      this.isGenericModalOpen = false;
      this.sessionStorageService.remove('isGenericModalOpen');
    }
    this.commonService.messageDetailsObs.subscribe(message => {
      if (message !== this.message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.setMsgObj();
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.id = this.commonService.modalID;
    this.my_modal_title = this.commonService.modalTitle;
    this.my_modal_content = this.commonService.modalMsg;
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.commonService.messageDetailsObs.subscribe((messageDetails) => {
      console.log('Message Details: ', messageDetails)
    });
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.modalService.remove(this.id);
    this.element.remove();
    this.sessionStorageService.remove('isGenericModalOpen');
    this.cdref.detach();
  }

  public checkRefDetectChanged(): void {
    if(!(<ViewRef> this.cdref).destroyed) {
      this.cdref.detectChanges();
    }
  }

  // open modal
  public open(): void {
    // this.element.style.display = 'block';
    // document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
    this.showModal = this.modalService.open(this.id);
  }

  // close modal
  public close(): void {
    // this.element.style.display = 'none';
    // document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
    this.showModal = false;
    this.commonService.showHideGenericModal('close');
  }

  // Set Modal Title
  public setTitle(title: string): void {
    this.my_modal_title = this.modalService.getTitle();
    this.modalService.setTitle(this.id, title);
    this.msgObj.title = this.my_modal_title;
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

  // Set Modal Message
  public setMsg(msg: string): void {
    this.my_modal_content = this.modalService.getMsg();
    this.modalService.setMsg(this.id, msg);
    this.msgObj.msg = this.my_modal_content;
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

  // Set the ID of the modal dynamically
  public setID(id: string): void {
    this.id = id;
    this.msgObj.id = this.id;
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

  // Get the ID of the modal set
  public getID(): string {
    return this.id;
  }

  public receiveMessage(event: any): void {
    this.message = event;
    console.log('Received Message: ', this.message);
    this.my_modal_title = this.commonService.modalTitle;
    this.my_modal_content = this.commonService.modalMsg;
    this.msgObj.id = this.commonService.id;
    this.msgObj.title = this.my_modal_title;
    this.msgObj.msg = this.my_modal_content;
    this.modalService.updateModal(this.msgObj);
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

  public get data(): any {
    return this.msgObj;
  }

  public setMsgObj(): void {
    this.message = this.msgObj;
  }


}
```

Here's the GenericModalObj from the interface file that @Krenom explained

```
export interface GenericModalObj {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  msg: string;
  msgObj: {}
}
```

Finally, this is my modal.service.ts

```
export class ModalService {
  modals: any[] = [];
  modalTitle!: string;
  modalMsg!: string;
  id!: string;
  showModal: boolean = false;

  theModal!: HTMLElement;

  add(modal: any) {
    // add modal to array of active modals
    this.modals.push(modal);
  }

  remove(id: string) {
    // remove modal from array of active modals
    this.modals = this.modals.filter(x => x.id !== id);
  }

  open(id: string): boolean {
    // open modal specified by id
    const modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    return this.showModal = false;
  }

  close(id: string): boolean {
    // close modal specified by id
    const modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    return this.showModal = true;
  }

  setTitle(id: string, title: string) {
    // Sets the title
    const modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    this.modalTitle = title;
    // modal.title = title;
  }

  setMsg(id: string, msg: string) {
    // Sets the title
    const modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    this.modalMsg = msg;
    // modal.msg = msg;
  }

  setID(id: string): void {
    this.id = id;
  }

  getID(): string {
    return this.id;
  }

  // Get Modal Title
  getTitle(): string {
    return this.modalTitle;
  }
  // Get Modal Msg/Body
  getMsg(): string {
    return this.modalMsg;
  }

  // In the Stackoverflow solution the options is options: 
  updateModal(options: GenericModalObj): void {
    const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === options.id);
    if (!modal) return;
    if (options.title) modal.title = options.title;
    if (options.message) modal.message = options.message;
  }

}
```

Here's where I send the modal msgObj from the FORM COMPONENT

```
  setModalAction(id: string, title: any, msg: any): void {
    // Send Message to emit
    this.messageOBJ.id = id;
    this.messageOBJ.title = title;
    this.messageOBJ.msg = msg;
    this.sendMessage(this.messageOBJ);
  }

  // Send Message Object to be listened for
  sendMessage(msgObj: Object): void {
    console.log('Sending Message: ', msgObj);
    this.messageEvent.emit(msgObj);
  }
```

and my settings at the top of this component

```
  @Output() setModalID: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() setModalTitle: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() setModalContent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<object>();
```

and the HTML for generic-modal.component.html

```
<div class="modal fade drag-block" (messageAction)="receiveMessage($event)" id="genericmodal" tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" [ngClass]="{'show': showModal}">
  <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title fxModalTitle">{{my_modal_title}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="close()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body fxModalBody">{{my_modal_content}}</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close()">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am just wondering how you are rendering your modal component and how it's connected to your component. There are different ways to communicate between angular components. Just need to know how your components are connected or how your DOM looks like

Comment: Let me take a screen shot of the dev console.  there's a main component, that calls the common-svc.service.ts, that sends the data to modal.service.ts and back to the common-svc.service.ts which EMITS the ID, TITLE and MSG (modal body) and the generic-modal.component.ts LISTENS for that EMITTER messageAction therefore, should populate the following @Inputs: id, my_modal_title and my_modal_msg but they are EMPTY although common-svc.service.ts is in-fact EMITTING the this.message with all the three elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok but in your posted code I see you are listening to the message event using ViewChild which I am not sure if this will work. I think the best is if you could create an example of your code in Stackblitz that we can at least have a full picture of your DOM structure to be able to help

Comment: Ok, it's going to take a little time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, not nearly enough time in a day to try and figure out how exactly that is all hooked up (you should consider refactoring and simplifying), but I suspect it's due to your inputs.

In a typical `@Input()` usage, you have some values set and ready, and then you show your component. The values are ready and you have them available at `ngOnInit()` time.

When dealing with opening dialogs, and using services and observables and all kinds of things that make things non-synchronous, it's quite possible that you don't have them at component init time.

The most basic fix is to wrap all your template parts with `*ngIf="someData"`, that way, if they're undefined to start with, nothing will show (and nothing will attempt to use the un-set variable) and you'll get no errors.

Once the value comes in, it'll show and all shall be good.

A slightly more advanced method, for use *with* the above, because you still need to prevent the template from accessing properties that aren't yet set - is to use setters.

```
private _data: any;
@Input() public set data(value: any) {
    this._data = value;
    this.onDataReceived();
}
public get data(): any { return this._data; }

private onDataReceived(): void {
    //... anything you might need to do once you get some input - sorting, processing, etc.
}
```

Typically though, only really need this if you plan on doing something with the value when it comes in, but always handy to know you can do this.

---

On the topic of refactoring, I think the simplest thing you can do is remove the split of id/title/message. It's tripling the amount of code that's there making it much harder to read and understand.

All three of those things are closely coupled and related to making one of your dialogs work. Keep them together, then. You already do, in your `component.ts`:

```
message = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    msg: '',
    msgObj: {}
};
```

All methods can be reduced to one update method with this one object as a param instead of several, and you only need to handle the update in one fashion.

```
public updateModal(options: ModalDataDto): void {
    const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === options.id);
    if (!modal) return;
    modal.title = options.title;
    modal.message = options.message;
}
```

If you don't keep track of that options object and anything could be making arbitrary guesswork updates to individual properties, then you can do checks before assigning so you don't accidentally overwrite:

```
public updateModal(options: ModalDataDto): void {
    const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === options.id);
    if (!modal) return;
    if (options.title) modal.title = options.title;
    if (options.message) modal.message = options.message;
}
```

That way, anything could update only a part of it:

```
    ...
    this.service.updateModal({id: 'asdf', title: 'New title'});
    ...
```

I notice that you can dynamically re-set the id as well. Not a fan of changing IDs because they're identifiers, and changing them is weird and not generally done, but if you are going to, I'd then suggest an additional property in your new options:

```
    if (options.newId) modal.id = options.newId;
```

---

Update for your update:

One thing I can see is, wrong, ish, but mostly pointless:

```
@Input() public set data(value: any) {
    this.message = value;
    this.data();
}
```

It's setting the message, huzzah, but then calling `this.data()` - which I can't see as a method in there anywhere. I can see a *getter*, but then usage would be `this.data` rather than as a method call. And it's just a getter, so that line wouldn't be doing anything.

I'll say the same thing as before - it's still too complicated to follow, especially at this time of the morning, so I'll guess.

It *looks* like it works this way, from what I can see:

The `modals` proper in `ModalService` is a list of your modals, right? Hard to tell without types. I assume by 'modal', we also mean actual `GenericModalComponent` instances? It looks like it.

You have the method to affect updates against these modals:

```
updateModal(options: GenericModalObj): void {
    const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === options.id);
    if (!modal) return;
    if (options.title) modal.title = options.title;
    if (options.message) modal.message = options.message;
}
```

Where it does `modal.title = ...`. However, I can't see any public properties for `title` or `message` in `GenericModalComponent`.
You have a `my_modal_title` as an input, and you have `setTitle(...)` as a method to do such, but you are using neither.

Presumably, if you used `if (options.title) modal.setTitle(options.title);` it would work.

Though maybe not... given the weird steps that method is doing.

If I'm reading it right, when you call `setTitle` it does the following:

Assume the service title is currently 'Service Title', and the modal title is currently 'Modal Title' - and we're going to call the modal's `setTitle('New Title')` method.

1. Sets its `@Input` title (`my_modal_title` ) to whatever value is currently stored in the `ModalService` - so that is now 'Service Title'.
2. It calls the `ModalService`'s `setTitle` method, which finds the modal, ignores it, and sets its own stored title to be the one given it - the service title is now 'New Title'.
3. It then sets the `msgObj` title to be the new one - ok, fine, but that msgObj doesn't look like it's used anywhere?
4. Then does detect changes - ok, fine, but we'll get to that.

So you've got a few compounding structural issues here that need to be sorted out.

Lets roll with change detection to start with, because I don't think you should ever generally need to worry about change detection unless you're doing something specific, which this doesn't feel like it is.

Assume a basic setup:

`thing.component.ts`

```
export class ThingComponent {
    public valueValue: string;
    public refValue: SomeObject;
    public arrayValue: SomeObject[];
}
```

and a basic template:

```
<div>Value type: {{valueValue}}</div>
<div>Reference type: {{refValue}} - {{refValue.someProperty}}</div>
<div>
    Array type: {{arrayValue}}

    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of arrayValue">{{item.someProperty}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When filled, you should see something like:

```
Value type: Whatever value was entered
Reference type: [Object object] - Whatever ref value was entered
Array type: [Object object, maybe Object array or whatever, I don't remember] 
  - Whatever ref value 1 was entered
  - Whatever ref value 2 was entered
```

Now, any updates `valueValue` should cause the view to update. Value types are immutable and Angular handles checking these nps.

Any updates to `refValue` is different, depending on how you use it. Angular won't, generally, be checking the internals of your object, so any change to `refValue.someProperty` may not actually be picked up. Guaranteed to be picked up is if `refValue` *itself* is changed.

If you had a getter, e.g. `public getRefValue(): string { return this.refValue.someProperty; }` then changes to `someProperty` should be picked up if that's used in the view instead, e.g. `<div>Value type: {{getRefValue}}</div>`.

This is because Angular generally hits the getters during its update cycles and at that point, it's just a string, not an object.

For anything referencing that object, however (e.g. any component `@Input()`s that you pass it in to), they will be looking at the *object* reference.

In that case, you can cheat and just create a new object (beware of shallow/deep clone issues) by using the shorthand: `this.refValue = {...this.refValue};` - now `refValue` is a copy of itself, but in a new object, so Angular's change detection will re-evaluate it.

This will trigger setter hits to your `@Inputs` whereas doing `this.refValue.someProperty = 'asdf';` wouldn't have.

Arrays are more fun, because they're more or less the same as objects. You can change the contents of an array, but that doesn't change the array object itself. Similar to objects, you can short-hand for copying, e.g. `this.arrayValue = [...this.arrayValue];` or, I think you can do `this.arrayValue = this.arrayValue.splice()` which also returns a copy.

Finally, after that essay, it my intended usage of the `GenericModalObj` object. It should be used in place of the multiple lines.

You can replace:

```
public id: string;
public title: string;
public message: string;
```

with:

```
public data: GenericModalObj;
```

And you don't need all those `setId`, `setTitle`, `setMessage`, and reduce down to the one `update` method that you, sort of, have in place. Also, any method that deals with more than one of those doesn't need multiple params, just the one. It's about reducing the code.

Id, title, message - all of these are closely coupled; you can't have a modal without them all so it suggests that, structurally, they belong together. So put them together in a type, and *make use of the typing* available with TS.

```
private doSomething(): string {...}
```

Tells everyone so much more than

```
doSomething() {...}
```

It's private, so I know it's not available to the template (if this is a component), or generally not available/used outside whatever class it's in.

I can see it's going to return a `string`, so I know it's not just a random processor method that will (possibly) alter the state of *something*. I mean, it might, but hopefully the naming will suggest that, but ideally it won't (one method does one thing...).

Making proper use of context like this helps to understand and follow what is happening with your code. Never write code that *you* understand because you wrote it, always write code so that idiots like *me* can read it. Others in the future, and Future You, will thank you for it.

Comment: This is good and I was just flipping out the ID for calling a specific modal but that's no longer required in your solution. ONE ID for DIFFERENT body and titles.  Simple logic. Let me implement tomorrow morning at work and get back to you. Thank you very much but I'm going to assume this will work and upvote and select as the solution in advance.

Comment: One question: Please forgive my ignorance. What is: options: ModalDataDto <<<--- Is that just "Object" datatype?  I've never seen that datatype. Please explain.

Comment: Yeah, just an object - where possible, it's best to define your objects so that you make make use of typing (for readability if nothing else) rather than leave it as a much larger, `{thing: string, other: number, etc: string}`. So make some `my-obj.dto.ts` or whatever your naming convention is and `export interface MyObjDto { thing: string; other: number; etc: string}` and just use that in place `public someMethod(input: MyObjDto): void {...}`.

Comment: Oh, it's an interface! I love using them and ENUMS. Now this makes sense! Thank you! This is right up my alley

Comment: I'm still having a wee bit of trouble... Everything's working but, when I open the MODAL, which does work, the data from MODAL BUTTON TWO, yes, I created a new modal button to send NEW content and title. I removed the requirement of changing the ID. That was not required.  I implemented your updateModal.... it's doing what it needs but the data for MODAL 2, which has "Title Modal 2" and "Content Modal 2" as strings being passed, are NOT going into the generic-modal.component.ts to populate the title and content @Inputs hence, it does it the first time for Modal1 not for Modal 2.  SEE UPDATE!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get the SUBSCRIBE and SEND MESSAGE to work! This solution is a combination of what Krenom did and what I was relentless in doing.

I'm keeping what Krenom has as a solution but I'm expanding on it.

Here's what I did.

1. I kept the HTML for generic modal
2. I've modified the Generic Modal Component (SEE BELOW)
3. I've modified the Common Service (SEE BELOW)
4. I've modified the call in the FORM component slightly (SEE BELOW)

**Generic Modal Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewRef } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'angular-web-storage';
import { CommonSvcsService } from 'src/app/services/common-svcs.service';
import { ModalService } from 'src/app/services/modal.service';
import { GenericModalObj } from '../va-form-21/vaForm21.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mymodal',
  templateUrl: './generic-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generic-modal.component.css']
})
export class GenericModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() my_modal_title!: string;
  @Input() my_modal_content!: string;
  @Input() id: string = '';
  @ViewChild('messageEvent') messageAction: any;
  showModal: boolean = false;
  @Input() public set data(value: any) {
    this.message = value;
    this.data();
  }

  @ViewChild('el') el: ElementRef | undefined;

  private element: any;
  private isGenericModalOpen: boolean = false;
  public message!: object;

  constructor(
    private modalService: ModalService,
    private sessionStorageService: SessionStorageService,
    private commonService: CommonSvcsService,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  msgObj!: GenericModalObj;

  ngOnInit() {
    const modal = this;
    this.element = this.el?.nativeElement;
    this.modalService.add(this);

    if (this.my_modal_content === undefined && this.my_modal_title === undefined) {
      this.my_modal_content = '';
      this.my_modal_title = '';
    } else {
      this.my_modal_title = this.modalService.getTitle();
      this.my_modal_content = this.modalService.getMsg();
    }

    if (this.isGenericModalOpen) {
      this.isGenericModalOpen = false;
      this.sessionStorageService.remove('isGenericModalOpen');
    }
    this.commonService.messageDetailsObs.subscribe(message => {
      if (message !== this.message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.setMsgObj();
      }
    });
    this.checkRefDetectChanged();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.id = this.commonService.modalID;

    if (this.my_modal_title && this.my_modal_title.length > 0) {
      this.my_modal_title = this.modalService.getTitle();
    }

    if (this.my_modal_content && this.my_modal_content.length > 0) {
      this.my_modal_content = this.modalService.getMsg();
    }
    this.checkRefDetectChanged();
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.commonService.messageDetailsObs.subscribe((messageDetails) => {
      console.log('Message Details: ', messageDetails);
      if (this.modalService.id.length > 0 &&
        this.modalService.modalTitle.length > 0 &&
        this.modalService.modalMsg.length > 0) {
        this.msgObj.id = this.modalService.id;
        this.my_modal_title = this.modalService.modalTitle;
        this.my_modal_content = this.modalService.modalMsg;
      }
      this.checkRefDetectChanged();
    });
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    if (this.modalService.id.length > 0 &&
      this.modalService.modalTitle.length > 0 &&
      this.modalService.modalMsg.length > 0) {
      this.id = this.modalService.id;
      this.my_modal_title = this.modalService.modalTitle;
      this.my_modal_content = this.modalService.modalMsg;
    }
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.modalService.remove(this.id);
    this.element.remove();
    this.sessionStorageService.remove('isGenericModalOpen');
    this.cdref.detach();
    this.my_modal_content = '';
    this.my_modal_title = '';
    this.id = '';
  }

  public checkRefDetectChanged(): void {
    if (!(<ViewRef>this.cdref).destroyed) {
      this.cdref.detectChanges();
    }
  }

  // open modal
  public open(): void {
    // this.element.style.display = 'block';
    // document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
    this.showModal = this.modalService.open(this.id);
  }

  // close modal
  public close(): void {
    // this.element.style.display = 'none';
    // document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
    this.showModal = false;
    this.commonService.showHideGenericModal('close');
  }

  // Set Modal Title
  public setTitle(title: string): void {
    this.my_modal_title = this.modalService.getTitle();
    this.modalService.setTitle(this.id, title);
    this.msgObj.title = this.my_modal_title;
    this.checkRefDetectChanged();
  }

  // Set Modal Message
  public setMsg(msg: string): void {
    this.my_modal_content = this.modalService.getMsg();
    this.modalService.setMsg(this.id, msg);
    this.msgObj.msg = this.my_modal_content;
    this.checkRefDetectChanged();
  }

  // Set the ID of the modal dynamically
  public setID(id: string): void {
    this.id = id;
    this.msgObj.id = this.id;
    this.checkRefDetectChanged();
  }

  // Get the ID of the modal set
  public getID(): string {
    return this.id;
  }

  public receiveMessage(event: any): void {
    this.message = event;
    console.log('Received Message: ', this.message);
    this.my_modal_title = this.commonService.modalTitle;
    this.my_modal_content = this.commonService.modalMsg;
    this.msgObj.id = this.commonService.id;
    this.msgObj.title = this.my_modal_title;
    this.msgObj.msg = this.my_modal_content;
    this.checkRefDetectChanged();
  }

  public get data(): any {
    return this.msgObj;
  }

  public setMsgObj(): void {
    this.message = this.msgObj;
  }


}
```

**Common Service**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'angular-web-storage';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { GenericModalObj } from '../components/form/Form.interface';
import { ModalService } from './modal.service';
import { FormelementService } from './Form.element.service';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    initAutocomplete: () => void;
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonSvcsService implements OnInit {

  modals: any[] = [];
  modalMsg: string = '';
  modalID: string = '';
  modalTitle: string = '';

  private _messageDetails: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  public messageDetailsObs = this._messageDetails.asObservable();

  startDate!: Date;
  endDate!: Date;
  currDate!: Date;
  vaFormData: any;
  showModal: boolean = true;

  autocomplete!: google.maps.places.Autocomplete;
  address1Field!: HTMLInputElement;
  address2Field!: HTMLInputElement;
  postalField!: HTMLInputElement;
  genericModal!: HTMLElement;
  id!: string;
  isGenericModalOpen: boolean = false;


  constructor(
    private sessionStorageService: SessionStorageService,
    private modalService: ModalService,
    private formService: FormelementService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.initAutocomplete = this.initAutocomplete;
    if (this.isGenericModalOpen) {
      this.isGenericModalOpen = false;
      this.sessionStorageService.set('isGenericModalOpen', this.isGenericModalOpen);
    }
    this.formService.regForSettingModalID(this.regForSettingModalID.bind(this));
    this.formService.regForSettingModalTitle(this.regForSettingModalTitle.bind(this));
    this.formService.regForSettingModalMsg(this.regForSettingModalMsg.bind(this));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sessionStorageService.remove('isGenericModalOpen');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.isGenericModalOpen) {
      this.isGenericModalOpen = false;
      this.sessionStorageService.set('isGenericModalOpen', this.isGenericModalOpen);
    }
  }

  checkDate(date1: Date, date2: Date): string {
    let retVal = "";
    this.currDate = new Date();
    this.startDate = new Date(date1);

    if (this.startDate.getTime() > this.currDate.getTime()) {
      retVal = "Your Entry Date cannot be greater than today's Date.";
    }


    return retVal;
  }

  initAutocomplete() {
    this.address1Field = document.querySelector("#homeaddress") as HTMLInputElement;
    this.address2Field = document.querySelector("#hmapt") as HTMLInputElement;
    this.postalField = document.querySelector("#hmpostal") as HTMLInputElement;

    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
    // addresses in the US and Canada.
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.address1Field, {
      componentRestrictions: { country: ["us", "ca"] },
      fields: ["address_components", "geometry"],
      types: ["address"],
    });
    this.address1Field.focus();

    // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
    // address fields in the form.
    this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", this.fillInAddress);
  }

  fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    const place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    let address1 = "";
    let postcode = "";

    // Get each component of the address from the place details,
    // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
    // place.address_components are google.maps.GeocoderAddressComponent objects
    // which are documented at http://goo.gle/3l5i5Mr
    for (const component of place.address_components as google.maps.GeocoderAddressComponent[]) {
      // @ts-ignore remove once typings fixed
      const componentType = component.types[0];

      switch (componentType) {
        case "hmaddy":
        case "bzaddy": {
          address1 = `${component.long_name} ${address1}`;
          break;
        }

        case "route": {
          address1 += component.short_name;
          break;
        }

        case "postal_code": {
          postcode = `${component.long_name}${postcode}`;
          break;
        }

        case "postal_code_suffix": {
          postcode = `${postcode}-${component.long_name}`;
          break;
        }

        case "hmcity":
        case "bzcity":
          (document.querySelector("#hmcity") as HTMLInputElement).value =
            component.long_name;
          break;

        case "administrative_area_level_1": {
          (document.querySelector("#hmstate") as HTMLInputElement).value =
            component.short_name;
          break;
        }

        case "hmcountry":
        case "bzcountry":
          (document.querySelector("#hmcountry") as HTMLInputElement).value =
            component.long_name;
          break;
      }
    }

  }

  regForCheckDate(checkDateCallback: Function): void {
    console.log('Check Date Callback: ', checkDateCallback);
  }

  regForfillInAddress(checkfillInAddressCallback: Function): void {
    console.log('Check fillInAddress Callback: ', checkfillInAddressCallback);
  }

  regForSettingModalID(checkSettingModalIDCallback: Function): void {
    console.log('Check for Modal ID', checkSettingModalIDCallback);
    this.formService.regForSettingModalID(checkSettingModalIDCallback);
  }

  regForSettingModalTitle(checkSettingModalTitleCallback: Function): void {
    console.log('Check for Modal Title', checkSettingModalTitleCallback);
    this.formService.regForSettingModalTitle(checkSettingModalTitleCallback);
  }

  regForSettingModalMsg(checkSettingModalMsgCallback: Function): void {
    console.log('Check for Modal ID', checkSettingModalMsgCallback);
    this.formService.regForSettingModalMsg(checkSettingModalMsgCallback);
  }

  showHideGenericModal(fromwhere: string): void {
    switch (fromwhere) {
      case "voice":
      case "button":
        this.openModalDialog();
        break;
      case "close":
        this.closeModalDialog();
        break;
    }
  }

  /**
 * Open Generic Modal
 */
  public openModalDialog(): void {
    this.genericModal = document.getElementsByClassName('drag-block')[0] as HTMLElement;

    this.isGenericModalOpen = this.sessionStorageService.get('isGenericModalOpen');

    let id = '', title = '', msg = '', msgObj = {};

    if (!this.isGenericModalOpen) {
      this.isGenericModalOpen = true;
      this.sessionStorageService.set('isGenericModalOpen', this.isGenericModalOpen);
      console.log('Inside openGenericModal: ', this.genericModal);
      this.id = this.modalService.getID();
      this.modalTitle = this.modalService.getTitle();
      this.modalMsg = this.modalService.getMsg();
      this.genericModal.classList.add('show');
      this.isGenericModalOpen = false;
      id = 'genericmodal';
      title = this.modalTitle;
      msg = this.modalMsg;
      msgObj = this.modalService.getMsgObj();
      // Send Message
      this.messageDetails({id, title, msg, msgObj});
      this.updateModal({
        id, title, msg,
        msgObj: {}
      });
      this.sessionStorageService.set('isGenericModalOpen', this.isGenericModalOpen);
    } else {
      // ('The modal is already opened');
    }
  }

  public closeModalDialog() {
    let isGenericModalOpen;
    isGenericModalOpen = false;
    this.genericModal = document.getElementsByClassName('drag-block')[0] as HTMLElement;
    this.sessionStorageService.set('isDebugModalOpen', isGenericModalOpen);
    // console.log('Inside closeDebugModal: ', isDebugModalOpen);
    this.genericModal.classList.remove('show')
  }

  public updateModal(options: GenericModalObj): void {
    const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === options.id);
    if (!modal) return;
    modal.title = options.title;
    modal.message = options.msg;
    modal.msgObj = options.msgObj;
  }

  messageDetails(message: Object): void {
    this._messageDetails.next(message);
  }

}
```

**Form Component**
Snippets from the full code

```
...
showHideGenericModal(event: any, key: any, showmodal: boolean): void {
    this.showModal = showmodal;
    if (event.target.id !== 'btnDemoModal1' && event.target.id !== 'btnDemoModal2') {
      return;
    } else {
      this.genericModalDialog = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.genericModalDialog = false;
      }, 5000)
      this.openModal(key, "Opening " + key);
    }
  }

  openModal(id: string, title: string): void {
    console.log('Opening the ' + id);
    let msgObj: Object = {};
    this.modalService.setID(id);
    this.modalService.setTitle(id, title);
    this.modalService.setMsgObj(id, msgObj)
    this.modalService.setMsg(id, this.getMsgBody(id));
    this.setModalAction(id, title, this.modalService.getMsg(), this.modalService.getMsgObj());
    // Make sure we set isGenericModalOpen to FALSE just in case it's still TRUE
    this.sessionStorageService.set('isGenericModalOpen', false);
    this.commonService.showHideGenericModal('button');
  }

  closeModal(id: string, modalname: string): void {
    console.log('Modal will close...' + id);
    this.modalService.id = modalname;
    this.modalService.setTitle(id, "");
    this.modalService.setMsg(id, "");
    this.commonService.showHideGenericModal('close');
  }

  setModalAction(id: string, title: string, msg: string, msgobj: object): void {
    // Send Message to emit
    this.messageOBJ.id = id;
    this.messageOBJ.title = title;
    this.messageOBJ.msg = msg;
    this.messageOBJ.msgObj = msgobj;
    this.sendMessage(this.messageOBJ);
  }

  // Send Message Object to be listened for
  sendMessage(msgObj: Object): void {
    console.log('Sending Message: ', msgObj);
    this.messageEvent.emit(msgObj);
  }

  getMsgBody(id: string): string {

    let msgBody = '';

    switch (id) {
      case "genericmodal1":
        msgBody = "This is the body text for modal 1";
        break;
      case "genericmodal2":
        msgBody = "This is the body text for modal 2";
        break;
      default:
        msgBody = "This is the default modal body text!"
        break;
    }
    return msgBody;
  }
...
```

Finally, you can pull the data for the modal body from a JSON object or database and modify your code accordingly.

The ngOnDestroy clears out the MODAL BODY and MODAL TITLE

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.modalService.remove(this.id);
    this.element.remove();
    this.sessionStorageService.remove('isGenericModalOpen');
    this.cdref.detach();
    this.my_modal_content = '';
    this.my_modal_title = '';
    this.id = '';
  }
```

**NOTE: the this.id is ONLY the ID of the modal body and title NOT the id of the generic modal component. Krenom said not to dynamically change the modal ID and I heeded his warning.**
Happy Coding!